# Refactoring/Loop though booleans with return statement

Tags: java

I'm trying to refactor code - for this I'd like to create a loop/array for these booleans:

```
boolean _1U() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() - 1][fieldOne()]; }
boolean _1D() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() + 1][fieldOne()]; }
boolean _1R() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero()][fieldOne() + 1]; }
boolean _1L() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero()][fieldOne() - 1]; }

boolean _1U1R() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() - 1][fieldOne() + 1]; }
boolean _1U1L() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() - 1][fieldOne() - 1]; }
boolean _1D1R() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() + 1][fieldOne() + 1]; }
boolean _1D1L() { return secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() + 1][fieldOne() - 1]; }
```

As for methods/button:

```
JButton[][] buttons = new JButton[12][12];
JTextField[] textField = new JTextField[4];

private JButton secondClicked() { return buttons[fieldTwo()][fieldThree()]; }
private int fieldZero() { return Integer.parseInt(textField[0].getText()); }
private int fieldOne() { return Integer.parseInt(textField[1].getText()); }
int fieldTwo() { return Integer.parseInt(textField[2].getText()); }
int fieldThree() { return Integer.parseInt(textField[3].getText()); }
```

I use booleans to:

```
void moveBlackPawn() {
    if (_1D1R() && !iNull() || _1D1L() && !iNull() || _1D() && iNull()) {
        doMove();
    }
}

void moveWhitePawn() {
    if (_1U1R() && !iNull() || _1U1L() && !iNull() || _1U() && iNull()) {
        doMove();
    }
}
```

I tried to put buttons into array (to test), but I end up with NPE.

```
boolean[] direction = {secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() - 1][fieldOne()], secondClicked() == buttons[fieldZero() + 1][fieldOne()]};

void moveBlackPawn() {
    if (_1D1R() && !iNull() || _1D1L() && !iNull() || direction[1] && iNull()) {
        doMove();
    }
}

void moveWhitePawn() {
    if (_1U1R() && !iNull() || _1U1L() && !iNull() || direction[0] && iNull()) {
        doMove();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to loop though these/make an array that will work?

Comment: You might be able to get a better answer on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)